# What is the difference between "stripe.handleCardPayment (clientSecret)" and "stripe.retrievePaymentIntent (clientSecret)"?

Tags: stripe-payments

**What is the difference below? Please tell me the pros and cons of each.**

・stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret)

```
(async () => {
  let {paymentIntent, error} = await stripe.handleCardPayment(clientSecret);
  if (error) {
    // Handle error here
  } else if (paymentIntent && paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
    // Handle successful payment here
  }
})();
```

---

・stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret)

```
(async () => {
  let {paymentIntent, error} = await stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret);
  if (error) {
    // Handle error here
  } else if (paymentIntent && paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
    // Handle successful payment here
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleCardPayment` tells Stripe to gather payment information and attempt to collect payment from your user, returning a PaymentIntent object upon success. [0](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-handle-card-payment)

`retrievePaymentIntent` retries the PaymentIntent without attempting any payment collection. [1](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-retrieve-payment-intent)

There aren't pros and cons as such as the two methods do very different things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At the time of the question, I did not notice that the behavior of the two was clearly different.